# Programatically loads Javascript file and load code when it's finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I'm working in a React project that uses jQuery and I need to import a jQuery library to it.

Basically, what I need right now is a way to load a javascript in my project dynamically and when it finishes loading I need to run a javascript code.

something like this:

```
$(function(){
 loadJavascript('myscript.js',function(){
  //run this code when myscript has finished loading
  });
});
```

Comment: And what's wrong with a regular script tag ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`$.getScript`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) does what you want.

```
$(function() {
    $.getScript('myscript.js', function() {
        // run when myscript has finished loading
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen RequireJS? It's a pretty nice library that does what you want
http://requirejs.org/

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, then try this.
Using JQuery, perform an jsonp ajax with a callback function name.
E.g.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/ny-app/getJSfunction",
    jsonp: "myfunctionName",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {
        q: "select title,abstract,url from search.news where query=\"cat\"",
        format: "json"
    },
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response ); // server response
    }
});
```

Handle this call on the server side, and return a function encapsulated javascript code that returns some data.
The returned javascript will look like this:

```
function myfunctioname(){
     // some code
     return 'whatever you want' ;
}
```

JQuery ajax will automatically execute the returned javascript function.

Hope this helps.